# UserPrincipal.Save() causes an ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

Consider the following pieces of code from an Active Directory service I have. In the `Rename()` method it always throws an `ObjectDisposedException`, "*Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'DirectoryEntry'.*"

This used to work fine, but I also have an `Add()` method and the two were 95% identical code. So, I opted for the `SetIdentity()` method to which I would pass the principal and the properties dictionary and go from there. The `Add()` method works, but that's because there's no underlying object to manipulate yet. The `Rename()` method fails because there is one.

I know that if I put the code from `SetIdentity()` back into `Rename()` it will work just fine, but I don't want to do that.

I've tried wrapping the `using` clause in `Rename()` in a `try/catch` block, but it didn't do anything. I've tried passing the principal and dictionary by `ref`, but that also didn't help. I've tried checking if the `DirectoryEntry` is null and it didn't help.

So, I'm guessing it can't be the code inside the `using` clause that's failing. What else should I look for?

When debugging with Visual Studio I can hover over the object and it's there and complete with properties and values, so I don't know where I'm supposed be looking...

```
public override void Rename(
    UserPrincipal principal,
    IDictionary<string, object> properties) {
    if (principal != null) {
        this.SetIdentity(ref principal, ref properties);

        using (DirectoryEntry entry = (principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry)) {
            entry.Rename(newName: String.Format("CN={0}", principal.DisplayName));
            entry.CommitChanges();
        };

        principal.Save(); // this is where ASP.NET runtime points to when failed
    };
} // this is where Visual Studio points to when debugging

internal void SetIdentity(
    ref UserPrincipal principal,
    ref IDictionary<string, object> properties) {
    object obj = null;
    string displayName = string.Empty;
    string givenName = string.Empty;
    string middleName = string.Empty;
    string samAccountName = string.Empty;
    string surname = string.Empty;

    if (properties.TryGetValue("GivenName", out obj)) {
        givenName = (string)properties["GivenName"];
    };

    if (properties.TryGetValue("MiddleName", out obj)) {
        middleName = (string)properties["MiddleName"];
    };

    if (properties.TryGetValue("Surname", out obj)) {
        surname = (string)properties["Surname"];
    };

    if (properties.TryGetValue("SamAccountName", out obj)) {
        samAccountName = (string)properties["SamAccountName"];
    };

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(middleName)) {
        displayName = String.Format("{0} {1}", givenName, surname);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(samAccountName)) {
            samAccountName = String.Format("{0}{1}", givenName[0], surname);
        };
    } else {
        displayName = String.Format("{0} {1}. {2}", givenName, middleName[0], surname);

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(samAccountName)) {
            samAccountName = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", givenName[0], middleName[0], surname);
        };
    };

    samAccountName = samAccountName.ToLower();

    principal.DisplayName = displayName;
    principal.GivenName = givenName;
    principal.MiddleName = middleName;
    principal.SamAccountName = samAccountName;
    principal.Surname = surname;
    principal.UserPrincipalName = String.Format("{0}@dryforce.com", samAccountName);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
   using (DirectoryEntry entry = (principal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry))
```

Buy the .NET designers a cigar for good method naming.  You are disposing the "underlying object" with the using statement.  You jerked the floor mat, the object that makes the class work is no more.  It is a dead parrot.  An equivalent would be, say, disposing StreamReader.BaseStream.  Trying to read from it after you did that is going to go Kaboom, can't read from a disposed underlying object.

It's not your job to dispose it, your code didn't create it.  Fix the problem by omitting the *using* keyword.

Comment: @Alex The possible reason for issue is that you were trying to set *sAMAccountName* to something which is not allowed. For more refer [A device attached to system is not functioning](http://usrlocal.com/2009/08/a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-functioning/)